# Transparent splash screen on the first (and only first) startup of an app for instructions (iOS)

Tags: ios, splash-screen, subview

I have a simple app where the buttons are in the form of logos rather than text.  Things like undo, reset, settings, etc...  I'm trying to keep the interface simple, so I just want to have instructions shown on the first ever startup of the app.  I've seen this done in other apps, where a transparent subview with labels is loaded, then touching the window dismisses the subview.

I currently have the launch count stored in NSUserDefaults, so I just need to figure out how to add the subview on top of the main view, which then gets dismissed on a touch.  I would like to just load a png that fits the screen size in the subview.

This seems simple, but I am having trouble not overcomplicating this process.

Thanks!

Comment: That link gets me to where I'm already at.  I should have been more clear that I'm at the point where I can detect if it's the first launch, but my first instinct was to load a whole other view, rather than a pop-up style view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for your NSUserDefaults for the first launc and if it is then you could display your image as a modalViewController and to dismiss it on touch use `touchesBegan` metod to dismiss this controller.

Comment: This seems to be the solution I'm looking for.  I'll give it a shot and update with what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

> This seems simple, but I am having trouble not overcomplicating this process.

What have you tried?

There's not much required to add a view to another view, but you don't even have to go that far. You could add your instructions view in your .xib/storyboard file and set it's `hidden` property to `YES`. Then all you need to do if the user is launching for the first time (or if they ask to see the instructions again) is flip the `hidden` property to `NO`, and then back to `YES` when they touch it.

Comment: I'm not using a storyboard.  There are only two views, a main view and a settings view.  I suppose I already know how to check whether it's the first launch by checking if the launchCount == 1.  I'm going to try using a modalViewController as Abhijit Chaudhari suggested, as that seems to be the solution I'm looking for.